# Why don't emacs keybindings work on Mint 17.1?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I'm migrating from Ubuntu to Mint and loving it so far.

One thing has been bugging me. On ubuntu I was able to run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

to get system-wide emacs keybindings, but this doesn't seem to work on Cinnamon.
I also tried changing the setting using the gnome3-tweak-tool, but that doesn't seem to work either. I've confirmed that the setting has stuck and even tried logging out/back in.

There are only really a couple of shortcuts I care about - CTRL-A to go to the beginning of the line. CTRL-K to kill the line, and CTRL-E to go to the end of the line, CTRL-D to delete a character.

Any ideas? If I can make those shortcuts individually that would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is only sort-of supported in Mint. I eventually found out that you can use this:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme 'Emacs'
```

Although Emacs keybindings don't work in a lot of cinnamon apps (like the file browser for example), they do work in Chrome and the text editor.

See the thread on github for more information:
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3816